# Preview for titles for sites with MathJax

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, titles

It would be helpful if the title could be included in the preview, since there is no way of knowing if the MathJax you have entered into your title is valid/does what you want until you actually post the question.

Is this a good idea, and if so, could it be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

You can preview title by copy-pasting it in the body of the post.

That said, my opinion is that complex formulas should be kept out of question titles, and in general TeX markup in titles should be kept to a minimum. Titles are shown in many places where TeX markup is not  rendered: title of the page, filtered questions view (on stackexchange.com), hot question list on other sites. SE app for Android does not render TeX in question titles either. In some places where TeX in title  does render, it degrades the layout. On top of all that, markup-heavy titles hinder search algorithms and thus decrease the visibility of question to people outside of SE.

So, I'd rather make it *more difficult* to use markup in titles, not easier.

Comment: Good points. However, often either clarity or tersity is sacrificed when trying to express mathematical ideas in words alone.

Comment: @CameronMartin I agree that sometimes formulas in titles are unavoidable. But the current state of the site suggests they are overused. The title does not have to express mathematical ideas; it only needs to express what the question is about.

Comment: Including some part of the question (including LaTeX) into title makes identification of duplicates much easier. (And it also makes easier to see what the question is about without viewing the whole question.) See the discussion here: [Using MathJax/TeX in the titles of questions - yes or no?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10617/using-mathjax-tex-in-the-titles-of-questions-yes-or-no) We also have [specific guidelines](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles) for using formulas in the title.

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof Shouldn't the title try to summarise the question? If this is true, then it _has_ to include mathematical ideas. Also isn't "The title does not have to express mathematical ideas; it only needs to express what the question is about." a bit contradictory, since all the questions on here _are_ about mathematical ideas?